# ASPX Page Not Found (Error 404), though it exists?

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, iis-express, windows-8.1

I have a C#.NET project and am having a problem with a single web forms, ASPX page when debugging my application. Most of my application works fine, but when I hit a particular page, I get an Error 404, resource not found. I don't understand this because the file does exist, and it exists in the path that is being referenced. And, I hit several other ASPX pages on the way to this one, without error.

Now, I should mention that this particular page was only recently added to the project. My coworker, who added the page, says he was able to get the page to work, but we have different environments. So, I'm sure that has *something* to do with it, but I don't know what. Below are the known details regarding the differences between our environments.

**My environment**

- Windows 8.1
- IIS Express
- Visual Studio 2013

**Co-workers environment**

- Windows 7
- IIS 7
- Visual Studio 2012

We are both running with the same source code, as well as the same site and application pool settings in IIS, which are pointed to run time 4.0 and in classic mode.

Does anyone here have any idea why this would happen, or what I might try to get past this?

Comment: Any routing in global.asax?

Comment: Thank you for the question. I am routing in global.asax because we also have an MVC component in our app. I can look into whether the routes are getting in the way. But, if that were it, wouldn't my co-worker also have the same problem?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891 404 is a very large category, so you should try to learn which subcategory you hit.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by switching to local iis and enabling the Static Content option in Windows Features.